# is there an easy way to find index array zeros in Fortran?

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, find, fortran

I'm searching for intrinsic fortran functions to help me find the array index with zeros, or other value.
I only found minloc function, but I think this is not suitable.
Is there an matlab find function equivalent in Fortran?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, see High Performance Mark's answer on how to do this with with the `PACK` instrinsic function.

If I needed to perform operations on all array elements that satisfy some condition, I would implement it using a combination of `DO` and `IF` constructs, for example:

```
INTEGER :: i
REAL,DIMENSION(10) :: a
REAL :: eps = someSmallNumber
...
DO i = 1,SIZE(a)
  IF( 0 > a(i)-eps .AND. 0 < a(i)+eps )THEN
    ...
  ENDIF
ENDDO
```

The range `(a(i)-eps,a(i)+eps)` is used above to prevent against comparison fail due to floating point arithmetic. If working with integers, an exact `==` comparison will do.

If only assignment operations to array elements are needed, you can achieve this using `WHERE` or `FORALL` constructs.

Comment: usually, the test is written : if(abs(a(i)) < eps) then

Answer (score 10):

Given an integer array such as:

```
testarr = [0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4]
```

then the expression

```
pack([(ix,ix=1,size(testarr))],testarr==0)
```

will return the indices of the elements in `testarr` equal to `0`.

I'll leave you to generalise or enhance this to deal with real numbers or to wrap it into a function to suit your purposes.

The Fortran 2008 standard adds a new intrinsic function `findloc` which offers to be the replacement for Matlab's `find` that the question seeks; the compiler I use most (Intel Fortran 13.1.1) doesn't seem to implement this yet.

Answer (score 0):

High Performance Mark's solution based on the `pack` intrinsic is short and elegant. However, if your array is relatively small, searching for a specific value with `pack` tends to be slower than a brute force search based on a `do` loop:

```
do i = 1, size(testarr)

  if (testarr(i) == 0) then

    idx = i
    exit

  end if

end do
```

See [Craig Finch's answer](http://www.shocksolution.com/2011/03/finding-value-in-unordered-fortran-array/) for details. I have also verified that brute force `do` loop is faster for small arrays (< 10 elements), compared to the `pack` based search.

Comment: That would account for its greater speed !